# How to Create and Save to Folders in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I'd like to be able to create folders to save a custom class containing an image and text information to IsolatedStorage. For instance a user will be able to take a picture, add a caption, and either create a new folder or save to an existing folder within the app. The user should be able to create folders within folders and then save items respectively. I was referencing some documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to couple with the CameraCaptureTask result.

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        //myImage.Source = bmp;

        //Request the user to add caption and folder to save
    }
}
```

**ImageItem.cs**

```
public BitmapImage CapturedImage
{
    get;
    set;
}

public string Caption
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Within the completed event I would like to display the image and request a caption from the user, and then allow them to select or create a folder to save the image. This is where I am having trouble implementing the correct solution. Is there a way I can somehow display existing folders and sub folders to the user to choose from? I know how to create and remove folders in IsolatedStorage but determining how to best show this to the user and ensuring the existing folder structure is current is where I am at a loss.

Comment: Your app will have access to the folder given to it by the OS when you install, so you don't have to worry about existing folder structure. Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks. ultimately what I need to do is be able to create nested folders within IsolatedStorage, and then somehow display this current structure in the View so a user can determine what folder they'd like to save their image to, otherwise create a new folder in some selected location in IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this [example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Storage-Recipes-def37077), the folder structure is shown like this.

[image]

you may want to have a look at the following methods in MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    private async void btnGetLocalFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // The code for this event handler has been refactored into a method
        // because it is called from multiple event handlers.
        await ListFilesInLocalFolderAsync();
    }

    private async void btnCreateFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new file with a random filename.
        string newFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string newFileName = Path.GetFileName(newFilePath);
        StorageFile newFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(newFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // Save the new file in the list of files created by this app.
        thisApp.filesToDelete.Add(newFile.Path);

        // Enumerate the files and folders in the local folder,
        // including the new file.
        await ListFilesInLocalFolderAsync();
    }

    private async void btnCreateFolder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a new folder with a default folder name.
        const string folderName = NEW_FOLDER_NAME;
        StorageFolder newFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        // Save the new folder in the list of folders created by this app.
        thisApp.foldersToDelete.Add(newFolder.Path);

        // Enumerate the files and folders in the local folder,
        // including the new folder.
        await ListFilesInLocalFolderAsync();
    }

    private async void btnWriteTextFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string textFilePath = await FileHelper.WriteTextFile(TEXT_FILE_NAME, AppResources.TextFileContent);

        // Save the new file in the list of files created by this app.
        thisApp.filesToDelete.Add(textFilePath);

        // Enumerate the files and folders in the local folder,
        // including the new file.
        await ListFilesInLocalFolderAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I will certainly check out the sample. Do you know if there is a read and write image file option in there?